# tns debug/build android returned with unexpected error

Tags: android, debugging, build, nativescript, tns

Before I proceed, let me explain that I am recently employed into this new company as a junior IT support. I mainly do hardware with very2 little programming knowledge.
Recently my company upgraded to a newer server and we have changed the location of the databases. However our apps are still pointing towards the old server url/location. I have been in contact with the app developers on how to change the configuration of the apk; in which it needs to be decompiled. They are engaged in a big project and was unable to assist me at this moment. Instead, they have given me the whole folder containing all the source code (Shown in the screenshot).

[APK Project Files Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuxfU.png)

I was asked to:-

1. Change the URL setting in on of the config.ts file contained in the res folder - done -
2. Recompile everything to APK so that the 'new' apk can be installed on our mobile android devices.

Upon reading the README file in the folder, it is obvious I am supposed to rebuild this apk app using nativescript.  Please see screenshots:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwqtj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTFW.png)

My questions / Issues :-

1. I have done the steps required in the README file such as:-

   a. Install [node js] (https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-x64.msi). Make sure to use  version > v10 LTS **(I am now using ver v12.22.12)**

   b. Install Nativescript CLI using git bash

   ```bash
   npm install -g nativescript
   ```

   **Done**

   c. Install Java SE Development Kit 8u201 **Done**

   d. Install [Android Studio] (https://developer.android.com/studio/) **Done**

   e. Create android emulator. **Done**

   f. Clone this repository. *<---- How is this done correctly? Do I copy the whole project folder and place it under an active working folder to generate the apk app? Please advise*
2. Do I run the .sh script PRIOR to running the related commands in tns such as 'tns android build' / 'tns android debug'?
3. I did a tns debug android using command prompt (Admin rights) in the folder path and received :-

[tns debug android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwF6.png)

4. I also did tns doctor just to check my configurations are correct or otherwise:-
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UsN7.png)

I DID refer back to the developer of this app, however he did not have any comments rather than the android apk was created using nativescript (duh!).  I have also send him the exact same question here however he is not replying as prompt as I expected.  Would appreciate if anyone with the expertise could assist and guide me moving forward.  Many thanks.